# LEFT JOIN - fetching all data from left table with no matches in the right one

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

In my project, I have two tables like this:

```
parameters (
    id PRIMARY KEY,
    name
)
```

and

```
parameters_offeritems (
    id_offeritem,
    id_parameter,
    value,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_offeritem, id_parameter)
)
```

*I'm not showing structure of `offeritems` table, because it's not necessary.*

Some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO parameters (id, name) VALUES
    (1, 'first parameter'), (2, 'second parameter'), (3, 'third parameter')

INSERT INTO parameters_offeritems (id_offeritem, id_parameter, value) VALUES
    (123, 1, 'something'), (123, 2, 'something else'), (321, 2, 'anything')
```

Now my question is - how to fetch (for given offer ID) list of **all** existing parameters, and moreover, if for the given offer ID there are some parameters set, I want to fetch their value in one query.

So far, I made query like this:

```
SELECT p.*, p_o.value FROM parameters p LEFT JOIN parameters_offeritems p_o
ON p.id = p_o.id_parameter WHERE id_offeritem = OFFER_ID OR id_offeritem IS NULL
```

But it fetches only those parameters, for which there are no existing records in `parameters_offeritems` table, **or** parameters, for which value are set only for the current offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all parameters, plus the value of any parameters set for a specific Offer Item, you need to move the Offer ID logic into the join like this (see below).

```
SELECT  p.*, p_o.value 

FROM    parameters p 

        LEFT JOIN parameters_offeritems p_o
        ON p.id = p_o.id_parameter 
        AND id_offeritem = OFFER_ID;
```

If you have logic in your `WHERE` clause referring to fields in a table you are doing a `LEFT JOIN` on, you effectively change your `JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` (unless you are checking for a NULL).

Answer (score 0):

The magic word you're looking for is OUTER JOIN. Jeff Atwood did a nice Venn-diagram explanation [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: Using FULL OUTER JOIN (I guess you mean't that) - with MySQL trick, using both LEFT and RIGHT joins merged with UNION - the effect is the same as with only LEFT JOIN used.

Answer (score 0):

Your query was almost perfect, just `WHERE` in wrong pace:

```
SELECT p.*, p_o.value FROM parameters p 
LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT * FROM parameters_offeritems 
     WHERE id_offeritem = OFFER_ID) as p_o
ON p.id = p_o.id_parameter
```